# Why still Go panic "send on closed channel" when I close on sender side?

Tags: go, channel

I have a `stopChan` to notify senders to close channel and a `sync.Once` to make sure only one sender can close the channel, but I still get a "send on closed channel" panic, why?

```golang
func muitiSenderClose() {
    const SenderNum = 3

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(SenderNum)

    intChan := make(chan int)

    stopChan := make(chan struct{})

    once := sync.Once{}
    for i := 0; i < SenderNum; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            needStop := false
            for {
                select {
                case <-stopChan:
                    needStop = true
                case intChan <- 1:
                case intChan <- 2:
                case intChan <- 3:
                }

                if needStop {
                    break
                }
            }
            once.Do(func() {
                fmt.Printf("%d want to close chan\n",i)
                close(intChan)
            })
            fmt.Println("End. [sender] %id", i)
        }(i)
    }
    sum := 0
    for e := range intChan {
        fmt.Printf("Receive %d\n", e)
        sum += e
        if sum > 10 {
            close(stopChan)
            fmt.Printf("Got %d\n", sum)
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("End. [receiver]")

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Close the channel when all senders are complete. The fact that you needed a `sync.Once` to close the channel should be an indication it's in the wrong place. You also have a data race, always check with the race detector.

Comment: You have multiple goroutines all sending on `intChan`. They can't all close it. Senders sharing a channel need to wait until *all senders are finished sending* before closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`go` concurrency is very powerful. Coordinating concurrency is *very* *hard*. Fortunately the `go` standard library has many tools to help with this. You should probably familiarize yourself with the `context` package.

`context.Context` use done-channels under the covers (similar to your `stopChan`) but have other mechanisms like cancelation chaining. They are also used throughout the `go` standard library for http, database and other blocking-type requests.

As @JimB has mentioned, usually `sync.Once` are rarely needed when coordinating producer/consumers. `chan`s and `sync.WaitGroup`s are usually enough.

Anyway, here's the coordination fix to your code using `context.Context`:

https://play.golang.org/p/QwszE_bW41X